# Upload a file with angular 4 and php script

Tags: javascript, php, angular, file-upload

I want to upload images from my Angular App.
For the moment I've got the template (as below)

```
<input
  type="file"
  id="newIcon"
  name="iconeRubric"
  (change)=iconChange($event)
>
```

I've also have the component which save the file in a variable on change, and on submit I want to call a php file to save the file on the server. I've got :

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("iconeRubric", this.newRubricForm.get("iconeRubric").value);

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

this.http.post('./uploadFile.php', formData, {
   headers: headers
}).map(res => res.text())
   .subscribe(data => {
   if(JSON.parse(data).upload){
      this.finishSubmit(); // change route, hide popUp  etc...
      alert("Upload OK");
   } else {
      alert("Upload error");
   }
});
```

Here I want pass the formData var to the php file. But how can I get it in php ?
I try `$file = $_POST['iconeRubric'];` but $file is always null

In an other project I already pass variables from angular to php, but only strings or json which are stringify with :

```
let param = 'param='+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(
      {"email":email,"password":password}));
this.http.post('./logIn.php', param, {
   headers: headers
}).map(res => res.text())
   .subscribe(data => {
   ...code...
});
```

and in logIn.php I can get values as :

```
<?php
   $json = urldecode($_POST['logUser']);
?>
```

So how can I get the file in php ?
Thank you for any help

Comment: Have you checked the manual and tried that? http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Do you mean the global $_FILES ? but the $_FILES will be empty no ?

Comment: Sorry Magnus, but I don't really understand what is that. I'm sorry, did I explain clearly the problem ? Don't hesitate to ask me :)